# Component, controller and context: wrong controller inside the component?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember.js 1.0.RC6

I have created a component (options-carousel) and I would like to render content inside this component.

The first `{{controller}}{{test}}` is displaying the correct value for **test** from the controller.

The second `{{controller}}{{test}}` is displaying the `OptionsCarouselComponent` for the controller and nothing for the **test** (because it seems a bad reference to the controller).

```
{{controller}}{{test}}
{{#options-carousel}}
<div class="active item">
    {{controller}}{{test}}
</div>
{{/options-carousel}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context inside a component is the component itself. This is by design, so that components will be isolated from surrounding context.

To access a property of your controller from within a component, pass it as an argument like:

```
{{controller}}{{test}}
{{#options-carousel test="test"}}
<div class="active item">
  {{controller}}{{test}}
</div>
{{/options-carousel}}
```

Comment: Tx, works perfectly.. The doc from ember.js is confusing...{{author}} {{#blog-post title=title}}
  <p class="author">by {{author}}</p>
  {{body}}
{{/blog-post}}